# Can I use a existed .tmLanguage file when I writing my own .tmLanguage file?

Tags: syntax, sublimetext2, tmlanguage

I am writing a .tmLanguage file to highlight the markdown file(.md), and there are some cpp codes in the markdown files. I want use the c++.tmLanguage (in Packages\C++) to solve the syntax problem. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to learn how to write language definitions is to look at existing ones. There are [plenty](https://packagecontrol.io/search/markdown) of existing Markdown syntax definitions in Package Control, so I'd suggest you look through them to see how things are structured.

Assuming you're using [`PackageDev`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageDev)'s `.YAML-tmLanguage` format, repositories for fenced code would look like this:

````yaml
repository:
  fenced-c:
    name: markup.raw.block.markdown markup.raw.block.fenced.markdown
    begin: (\s*```)\s*(c)\s*$
    end: (\1)\n
    captures:
      '1': {name: punctuation.definition.fenced.markdown}
      '2': {name: variable.language.fenced.markdown}
    patterns:
    - include: source.c

  fenced-c++:
    name: markup.raw.block.markdown markup.raw.block.fenced.markdown
    begin: (\s*```)\s*(c\+\+)\s*$
    end: (\1)\n
    captures:
      '1': {name: punctuation.definition.fenced.markdown}
      '2': {name: variable.language.fenced.markdown}
    patterns:
    - include: source.c++

  fenced-coffee:
    name: markup.raw.block.markdown markup.raw.block.fenced.markdown
    begin: (\s*```)\s*(coffee)\s*$
    end: (\1)\n
    captures:
      '1': {name: punctuation.definition.fenced.markdown}
      '2': {name: variable.language.fenced.markdown}
    patterns:
    - include: source.coffee

  # etc.
````

Translated to XML using the built-in conversion tool, that would look like so:

````xml
<key>repository</key>
<dict>
    <key>fenced-c</key>
    <dict>
        <key>begin</key>
        <string>(\s*```)\s*(c)\s*$</string>
        <key>captures</key>
        <dict>
            <key>1</key>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>punctuation.definition.fenced.markdown</string>
            </dict>
            <key>2</key>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>variable.language.fenced.markdown</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>end</key>
        <string>(\1)\n</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>markup.raw.block.markdown markup.raw.block.fenced.markdown</string>
        <key>patterns</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>include</key>
                <string>source.c</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>fenced-c++</key>
    <dict>
        <key>begin</key>
        <string>(\s*```)\s*(c\+\+)\s*$</string>
        <key>captures</key>
        <dict>
            <key>1</key>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>punctuation.definition.fenced.markdown</string>
            </dict>
            <key>2</key>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>variable.language.fenced.markdown</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>end</key>
        <string>(\1)\n</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>markup.raw.block.markdown markup.raw.block.fenced.markdown</string>
        <key>patterns</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>include</key>
                <string>source.c++</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>fenced-coffee</key>
    <dict>
        <key>begin</key>
        <string>(\s*```)\s*(coffee)\s*$</string>
        <key>captures</key>
        <dict>
            <key>1</key>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>punctuation.definition.fenced.markdown</string>
            </dict>
            <key>2</key>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>variable.language.fenced.markdown</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>end</key>
        <string>(\1)\n</string>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>markup.raw.block.markdown markup.raw.block.fenced.markdown</string>
        <key>patterns</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>include</key>
                <string>source.coffee</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
<!-- and so on... -->
````

I urge you to use `PackageDev`, as YAML is *so* much easier to work with than XML. Alternatively, you can use the new YAML-based [`.sublime-syntax`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html) format, but it is currently only supported in the Sublime Text 3 [development builds](https://sublimetext.com/3dev) 3084 and later, which means you need to be a registered user to access it. I'd recommend sticking with `.YAML-tmLanguage` for now, until a new [public build](https://sublimetext.com/3) is released with support for the new format.

You can look in the `PackageDev` [Github repo](https://github.com/SublimeText/PackageDev) to find more examples of `.YAML-tmLanguage` files. Additionally, I am the lead developer on the [`Python Improved`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Improved) project, and you can find all my source files [on Github](https://github.com/MattDMo/PythonImproved) as well.